# Proof that a function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is differentiable at a point $a$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I struggle with a proof in multivariable calculus:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function that is differentiable at $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{a\}$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}^2$. The limit $\lambda:=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\nabla f(x)$ exists. Show that $f$ is differentiable at the point $a$, also show that $\nabla f(a)=\lambda$.

I think this statement can be proven by using the Mean Value Theorem for multiple variables, but I don't know how to do it. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried to show it in one dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
f(a+h)-f(a) - \lambda h &=& f((a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2))-f((a_1,a_2+h_2))  \\
& & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  +f((a_1,a_2+h_2)) - f(a) - \lambda h \\
&=& {\partial f(a_1+\xi_1,a_2+h_2) \over \partial x_1}h_1 + {\partial f(a_1,a_2+\xi_2) \over \partial x_2}h_2 - \lambda h
\end{eqnarray}
for some $\xi_1 \in (a_1,a_1+h_1), \xi_2 \in (a_2,a_2+h_2)$.

Since ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} \to \lambda$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find some $\delta>0$ such that
$\|{\partial f(a+h) \over \partial x} - \lambda\| <\epsilon$ for all
$\|h\| < \delta$. Then the above shows that
$\|f(a+h)-f(a) - \lambda h \| \le \epsilon \|h\|$. Hence $f$
is differentiable at $a$ with derivative $\lambda$.

**Alternative**:

Note that ${\partial f(x) \over \partial x}$ is bounded in a punctured neighbourhood of $a$, and so is bounded on any segment of the form $(a,x)$ (that is, the line segment not including end points) as long as $x$ is in this punctured neighbourhood.

Hence for any sufficiently small $h$, the function $\phi(t)=f(a+th)$ is absolutely continuous and so
$\phi(1) = \phi(0) + \int_0^1 \phi'(t) dt$.

Hence $f(a+h) - f(a) - \lambda h = \int_0^1 ({\partial f(a+th) \over \partial x}-\lambda)dt h$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $\delta>0$ such that
$\|{\partial f(x) \over \partial x}-\lambda\| < \epsilon$ whenever 
$\|h\| < \delta$. Then
$\|f(a+h)-f(a) - \lambda h \| \le \epsilon \|h\|$.

Comment: Can we be certain that $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ is bounded at $a$?

Comment: @md2perpe: If the given limit exists, then it must be bounded by $\|\lambda\| + \epsilon$.

Comment: The derivative is clearly bounded on a *punctured* neighbourhood of $a$, but we don't even know that the derivative exist at $a$ so can we conclude that $f$ is Lipschitz at $a$? Isn't that needed for $\phi$ to be absolutely continuous?

Comment: @md2perpe: Choose a convex neighbourhood of $a$ such that the derivative is bounded. Pick two points $x_0,x_1$ in this neighbourhood. If $a \notin (x_0,x_1)$ then the derivative bound applies. If $a \in (x_0,x_1)$ then split in interval into two parts $[x_0,a]$ and $[a,x_1]$ and now use the mean value theorem to show that the same bound applies.

Comment: @md2perpe: While the assertion above is correct, from the proof perspective one only needs to bound the derivative on segments of the form $(a,x)$ to obtain the formula for $\phi$ above.

Comment: @md2perpe: I reworded my answer a bit to remove the locally Lipschitz part.

Comment: The continuity of $f$ at $a$ must come in somehow. I suppose that's when concluding that $\phi$ is AC.

Comment: @md2perpe: The key underlying result is the ordinary mean value theorem which requires $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. This is where continuity is implicitly used.